# Spark streaming data from kafka topic and write into the text files in external path

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I want to read a data from kafka topic and group by key values, and write into text files..

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SparkSession spark=SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("Sparkconsumer")
                .master("local[*]")
                .getOrCreate();
        SQLContext sqlContext = spark.sqlContext();
        SparkContext context = spark.sparkContext();
        Dataset<Row>lines=spark
                .readStream()
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
                .option("subscribe","test-topic")
                .load();
    Dataset<Row> r=  lines.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)");
        r.printSchema();
        r.createOrReplaceTempView("basicView");
        sqlContext.sql("select * from basicView")
        .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
        .writeStream()
        .outputMode("append")
        .format("console")
        .option("path","usr//path")
        .start()
        .awaitTermination();
```

Comment: format(”console“) writes to console/stdout and not into a file. Use json or csv instead as parameter

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Not sure I understand why you'd use Spark for this

Comment: @AydinK. I know that one but when I run this program it will create folder and nothing in that folder.. that's the error

Comment: @cricket_007  I want streaming the data from Kafka topic..

Comment: Sure, and `kafka-console-consumer` or `kafkacat`, or the Kafka Java API works fine for this. Spark is just too large of a dependency for such a simple question

Comment: @cricket_007 ha Bro I know that one, I want read a data from Kafka and spark streaming will be write into diff file system. Even if I have large amount of data I want streaming using spark

Comment: Okay, well, I suggest don't think having `format("console")` makes sense if you actually want to write to a file system

Comment: @Paunraj  have you got any solutions for this ? i am facing same issue

Answer (score 1):

Following points are misleading in your code:

- To read from Kafka and write into a file, you would not need `SparkContext` or `SQLContext`,
- You are casting your `key` and `value` twice into a string,
- the `format` of your output query should not be *console* if you want to store the data into a file.

An example can be looked up in the [Spark Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html) and the [Spark Structured Streaming Programming Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html)

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  SparkSession spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("Sparkconsumer")
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate();

  Dataset<Row> lines = spark
    .readStream()
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    .option("subscribe","test-topic")
    .load();

  Dataset<Row> r = lines
    .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
    // do some more processing such as 'groupBy'
    ;

  r.writeStream
    .format("parquet")        // can be "orc", "json", "csv", etc.
    .outputMode("append")
    .option("path", "path/to/destination/dir")
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/path/to/checkpoint/dir")
    .start()
    .awaitTermination();
```